# How to Read data from CouchDB in RoR?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, database, json, couchdb

I'm developing a web application using RoR and MySQL, problem is, I need to read original data from CouchDB and insert that into MySQL database daily.

Is there any idea that how to read the CouchDB data to MySQL in RoR?

**Points to be Noted:**

- My application uses MySQL database
- Data stored in CouchDB is in JSON format
- I need only some of the available data from CouchDB not all

Comment: You can try and take a look at couchrest.
http://www.couchrest.info

Comment: @Rasmus API info not available there :(

Comment: but I am pretty sure there is a link to their github

Answer (score 1):

My solution would be to write a [CouchRest Model](http://www.couchrest.info/model/index.html) for each piece of info I want to get from CouchDB, so I can access CouchDB in a similar way as MySQL. Than you can write a rake task to update the MySQL database and schedule it to run once a day.

For example you can create the model as described at ["Defining a model"](http://www.couchrest.info/model/definition.html) and then query by _id as described at ["Querying"](http://www.couchrest.info/model/querying.html#get).

Comment: See the Data that I need to access stored like this, {"total_rows":7,"offset":0,"rows":[
{"id":"7d50b411ca641dcf6288d192ec001fff","key":"7d50b411ca641dcf6288d192ec001fff","value":{"rev":"4-025df209360b85a70cd7cd0686008247"}},
{"id":"7d50b411ca641dcf6288d192ec002b97","key":"7d50b411ca641dcf6288d192ec002b97","value":{"rev":"1-66de3e2b08394d348a1c770b63191e3b"}},
{"id":"Nagesh, Mysore, Karnataka","key":"Nagesh, Mysore, Karnataka","value":{"rev":"2-c8107dc2c46c3988508a63d7ba6ffb35"}}
]} I need to access each id from it using RoR

Comment: @ShreekumarS Getting by _id it's easy. I have added a link to the "querying" documentation.